# insert comma separated array in mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, insert

I am working on a script where I want to select parent id for a new user and save his parent id along with parents parent ids in mysql table.

```
$last_id = mysql_insert_id(); 

//select parent id of last inserted user 
$sel = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_new_agent WHERE new_agnt_id = '".$last_id."'"); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sel); 
$a = $row['new_agnt_ParentId']; 

//select parents of parent which are supposed to be stored at parent_arr field in db as comma separated values                                      
$sel1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_new_agent WHERE new_agnt_id = '".$a."'"); 
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sel1); 

//here i want to add element in array.though its not working obviously 
$b = array_push($row1['parent_arr'],$a); 

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_new_agent SET parent_arr = '".$b."' WHERE new_agnt_id = '".$last_id."'");
```

I have no idea how I can store comma separated values or store a single value initially and then add more elements.Can anyone give me idea in this regard?

Comment: Please consider reading about normalization. Storing comma-separated values in a column is *Data Base Bad Idea Number One*.

Comment: ok.I will use this data in another form where user selects an agent and by using in_array or something like that I will display text boxes in front of agent names.so far its simplest method for me

Comment: You shouldn't need this comma separated list. You'll just be storing the data twice. One way joins are enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you get a comma-separated list of a user's "Parents", no need for an additional column:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t2.new_agnt_id)
FROM tbl_new_agent t1
JOIN tbl_new_agent t2
ON t2.new_agnt_id = t1.new_agnt_ParentId
WHERE t1.new_agnt_id = :last_id
```

For performance sake, consider naming only the columns you need, instead of generically using `SELECT *` for everything. E.g. `SELECT new_agnt_ParentId FROM tbl_new_agent WHERE ...`.

Comment: thanks @Marcus Adams I have run your query.It is fetching parent of last inserted user.what im trying here to get array of parents also.

Comment: @user3388361. If the above query isn't pulling all parents, I may have guessed your schema wrong. If you're not going to provide your schema and some sample data, hopefully you can derive your answer from my example.

Answer (score 0):

for now i have found this solution:

`$update = mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_new_agent SET parent_arr = CONCAT('".$b."','".$a."',',') WHERE new_agnt_id = '".$last_id."'");`

and using in this way in another page:

```
     $agent_id = $_POST['comm_Agent'];  
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_new_agent");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
             $parent_arr = explode(',',$row['parent_arr']);
                   if (in_array($agent_id, $parent_arr)) {
                                echo $row['new_agnt_id'];
                   }

}
```

i am sure there are other 'neat' ways to achieve this.but so far above code is working as expected. thanks for your reply  Marcus Adams